# Trouble importing a module in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a dungeon developing program, and I have a number of modules I am using. I have a main module, a floor module, a room module, and a tile module. Floors are girds of rooms which are grids of tiles. In my floor module, I import Room so that I can store a two dimensional list of Rooms, but I keep getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\Rishabh\workspace\Bonding\Bonding\src\MainWork.py", line 15, in <module>
  floor = Floor.Floor()
 File "C:\Users\Rishabh\workspace\Bonding\Bonding\src\Floor.py", line 6, in __init__
  rooms = [[Room.RoomClass(i, j) for i in range(7)] for j in range(7)]
 File "C:\Users\Rishabh\workspace\Bonding\Bonding\src\Floor.py", line 6, in <listcomp>
  rooms = [[Room.RoomClass(i, j) for i in range(7)] for j in range(7)]
 File "C:\Users\Rishabh\workspace\Bonding\Bonding\src\Floor.py", line 6, in <listcomp>
  rooms = [[Room.RoomClass(i, j) for i in range(7)] for j in range(7)]
NameError: global name 'Room' is not defined
```

My code is as follows.

**Mainwork.py**

```
import Enemy
import Player
import Ribbon
import random
import Floor
import Room
import pygame as pyg
pyg.init()

screenWidth = 1280
screenHeight = 720
Player.health = 100
FPS = 60

floor = Floor.Floor()
floor.printgrid()

def mainLoop():
    pass
```

**Floor.py**

```
class Floor(object):

    import Room

    def __init__(self):
        rooms = [[Room.Room(i, j) for i in range(7)] for j in range(7)]
        current = [0, 0]
        roomStack = []
        totalRooms = 49
        visitedRooms = 1
```

**Room.py**

```
class Room(object):

    import Tile

    def __init__(self, floorx, floory, layout=[[0 for i in range(13)] for j in range(7)]):
        self.floorx = floorx
        self.floory = floory
        self.doors = [False, False, False, False]  # N,S,E,W
        for i in layout:
            for j in i:
                self.layout[i][j] = Tile.Tile(layout[i][j])
```

**Tile.py**

```
class Tile(object):

    def __init__(self, state):
        self.state = state
```

I have no idea what the problem could be at all. Thanks in advance

Comment: total overuse of classes

Comment: Please do not try to write Java in Python.

Comment: What do you mean Java in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Floor.py` the `import Room` is a `class` attribute so, you have to use class object to access it. Try using....

```
import Room

class Floor(object):

    def __init__(self):
        # other code goes here ....
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm still pretty new to python